# Is it possible to create a dartdoc on a Flutter Application?

Tags: dart, flutter

If I try to creat an Doc with dartdoc on an Flutter Application I get

[error] Invalid override. The type of 'AddLinkPage.createState' ('() → AddLinkPageState') isn't a subtype of 'StatefulWidget.createState' ('() → State')

and

[error] Classes can only extend other classes.

```
class AddLinkPage extends StatefulWidget {
   AddLinkPage({Key key,}):super(key: key);
   @override
   AddLinkPageState createState() {
      return AddLinkPageState();
   }

}
 class AddLinkPageState extends State<AddLinkPage>{
 ...
```

If I change my code to

```
class AddLinkPage extends StatefulWidget {
   AddLinkPage({Key key,}):super(key: key);
   @override
   createState() {
      return AddLinkPageState();
   }
}

 class AddLinkPageState extends State<AddLinkPage>{
 ...
```

I avoid the first error but the second still there and the generation of the dartdoc failed.

Is the dartdoc only for packes, plugin, module without application or do I something wrong?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon and a `}` on `AddLinkPage`, or it's just a random piece of code?

Comment: you are right. sorry I edit this

Comment: It looks like you have another object with the name `State`.

Comment: If you want to generate docs on your own, there currently are some other steps you need to generate links to Flutter documentation.  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24808

Comment: OK. All I had to do was update my dart with the Dart Update.exe. Now there are "909 warnings and 1 error", but a document is generated, this is enough for me at the moment